# How to send variable to wp meta_query value?

Tags: meta-query

I try to to make compare by company title so I need to send this title as variable to meta query value. I use this code and get value = NULL. Please tell me why?

```
        $company_name = the_title( );
        $params = array(
         'meta_query' => array(
           array( 
           'key' => 'user_company',
           'value' => $company_name
          )
         )
       );
```

Comment: `the_title` does not return the title, it echo's the title, it's the wrong function

Comment: But var_dump ($company_name) gives me the company title...

Comment: Thank you! I use get_the_title() and it works now.

Comment: `the_title` is the wrong function, even if it returns a value it still outputs to the browser, you must use the dedicated function that returns the title instead, `get_the_title`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get_the_title` to get the title. `the_title` is for when you want to output directly to the browser.